# Searching a string by binary search

Tags: c, string, binary-search

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[11];
    int score;
} report;

int main() {
    int n = 3;
    report student[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        scanf("%[^\#]#%d", student[i].name, &student[i].score);
    }

    // Input name that we search.
    char search[11];
    scanf("%s", search);

    // bubble sort
    for (int a = 0; a < n - 1; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < n - 1 - a; b++) {
            if (student[b].score < student[b+1].score) {
                report temp;
                strcpy(temp.name, student[b].name);
                temp.score = student[b].score;

                strcpy(student[b].name, student[b+1].name);
                student[b].score = student[b+1].score;

                strcpy(student[b+1].name, temp.name);
                student[b+1].score = temp.score;
            }
        }
    }

    // binary search 
    int left = 0;
    int right = n - 1;
    int middleIndex;
    int rank;
    while (left <= right ) {
        middleIndex = (int)(left + right) / 2;
        if (strcmp(student[middleIndex].name, search) == 0) {
            rank = middleIndex+1;
            break;
        } else if (strcmp(student[middleIndex].name, search) > 0) {
            left = middleIndex + 1;
        } else if (strcmp(student[middleIndex].name,search) < 0) {
            right = middleIndex - 1;
        }
    }

    // Rank of the student's name that we search.
    printf("%d", rank);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to create a program that will return a student ranking (from 3 students). The fourth line is the name that we searched. I put all the user input into a struct and sort it in descending order to represent students ranking. But the problem is, when it reach the binary search, it always return unexpected value. Could you guys help me solve the problem?

Sample Input :

```
Jojo#40
Ray#60
Liz#80
Jojo  -> name that we searched.

""" [ {Liz, 80}, {Ray, 60}, {Jojo,40} ] """
```

Output : 3

Comment: You sort by scores and then search by name using a search that relies on the items being in order by name. That does not work. A binary search relies on being able to decide whether the item being sought is later or earlier in the list according to whether the search key is greater than or less than the item key. The list must be ordered by the key being used to search, not by a different key.

Comment: Your `scanf` format string is wrong to begin with. I get this warning: `warning: unknown escape sequence: '\#'  15 |     scanf("%[^\#]#%d", student[i].name, &student[i].score);`. Start fixing this.

Comment: ... and your bubble sort doesn't work. You should fix this first. Your approach is wrong. You need to solve one problem at a time. First ensure that your bubble sort is correct. Once this works you can start the binary search. It's pointless to do a binary search on an unsorted list.

Comment: how to format the input based on this case?

Answer (score 0):

At least one problem is that your names (except the first) will have a newline as the first character. That newline was left in the input stream when scanning the score.

Consequently your string compare doesn't work.

Add this

```
for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) printf("|%s|\n", student[a].name);
printf("|%s|\n", search);
```

just after scan of `search` and you get the output:

```
|Jojo|
|
Ray|
|
Liz|
|Jojo|
```

As you can see there are "unexpected" newlines in front of both "Ray"  and "Liz"

To solve that add a space here

```
scanf(" %[^\#]#%d"
       ^
       space
```

As noted by @EricPostpischil in a comment, sorting by score and doing binary search by name makes no sense. The sort and the search must be based on the same.

BTW: When sorting arrays use `qsort`

Comment: My bad. I don't realize that sort by score and search by name. Could you guys give recommendation for what can i do for it?

Comment: @azio If you want to do binary search for a name, you must sort by names. If you want to do binary search for a score, you must sort by scores. It's a easy as that.

Comment: Suggesting `scanf(" %[^\#]#%d"...` without a width is as good as `gets()`.  Better as `scanf(" %10[^\#]#%d"...`